# Kendo DropDown List Trigger Change gives "n is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mvvm

```js
function GenericSelectFirst(e) {
    $("#LocationEdit_ddlSiteCode").data("kendoDropDownList").value(siteValue);  
    $("#LocationEdit_ddlSiteCode").data("kendoDropDownList").trigger('change'); // This line throws the javascript error
   
}
```

```html
<select id="LocationEdit_ddlSiteCode" class="full-width"
        data-bind="source: DataSource.SiteCodeDropDown, value: ViewModel.SiteCode, events:{dataBound: Function.GenericSelectFirst, change:Function.GenerateLocationCode}"
        data-role="dropdownlist"
        data-value-primitive="true"
        data-value-field="Code"
        data-text-field="Code"
>
</select>
```

I have a simple kendo dropdownlist, and on its DataBound event, I am trying to set the value and trigger the change event of it.

However, the trigger code gives `n is not a function` in the Chrome console, what have I done wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Kendo's ASP.NET framework, but can you provide the definitions for `DataSource`, `ViewModel`, and `Function`?

Comment: did you perhaps get a solution? I'm running now to the same issue

Comment: I'm also running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

After decades of googling, debugging, and testing i finally make it running by putting the binding code in

`$( document ).ready(function() {}`
then put kendo.bind() into setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ kendo.bind("#view", viewModel); }, 0.0001);
```

If you stuck in way to make it running without throw error "n is not a function" i think this solution will help. I will update my answer later if i can figure out why this happen.